# AWS ec2 instance unable to ssh inside

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create a ec2 instance but I am facing a problem where I am totally unable to ssh inside even if my security group has port 22 opened.

My terraform looks like this.

```hcl
variable "path_to_public_key"{
  default = "/<path-to-ssh>/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
}
resource "aws_vpc" "demo-vpc" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
  tags = {
    Name = "Ec2-EFront-Demo-Vpc"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "efront-subnet" {
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.demo-vpc.id
  cidr_block        = "10.0.1.0/24"
  availability_zone = "eu-west-1a"

  tags = {
    Name = "EFront-Subnet"
  }
}

resource "aws_network_interface" "efront-network-interface" {
  subnet_id   = aws_subnet.efront-subnet.id
  private_ips = ["10.0.1.100"]


  tags = {
    Name = "Efront_primary_network_interface"
  }
}

resource "aws_key_pair" "efront-ssh-key" {
  key_name = "id_rsa"
  public_key = "${file(var.path_to_public_key)}"
}

resource "aws_security_group" "allow-ssh-single" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.demo-vpc.id
  name = "allow-ssh-access"
  description = "security group that allows ssh and all egress traffic"

  egress {
    from_port = 0
    protocol = "-1"
    to_port = 0
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  ingress {
    from_port = 22
    protocol = "tcp"
    to_port = 22
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  tags = {
    Name = "allow-ssh"
    Environment = "Prod"
  }

}

data "aws_ami" "ubuntu"{
  most_recent = true
  filter {
    name = "name"
    values = ["ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-xenial-16.04-amd64-server-*"]

  }
  filter {
    name = "virtualization-type"
    values = ["hvm"]
  }

  owners = ["099720109477"] # Canonical
}

resource "aws_instance" "Efront-DEMO" {
  ami           = data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id
  instance_type = "t3a.small"
  subnet_id = aws_subnet.efront-subnet.id
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.allow-ssh-single.id]
  key_name = aws_key_pair.efront-ssh-key.key_name

  tags = {
    Name = "EFront-DEMO"
  }
}
```

The terraform init and apply runs without any problem. the instance is healthy, but when I try to ssh inside the virtual machine. I get:

`ssh: connect to host <IP> port 22: Operation timed out`

My security group allows access through port 22 and this is the only security group I have in place.

I tried to change the chmod to 400 not he key swell, but nothing.

Any advice about why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check:

1. That you are connecting to the public IP of the EC2.
2. That you do not have any restriction on your NACL (Network Access
   Lists)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I tried to connect from my browser to the public ip, but the connection doesn't go through. I added the port 80 and 443 to my security group but still nothing. I am not able to access or open the ip directly. My ACL allows everything and has the rule 100 as first and only

Comment: Have you checked that you do not have a firewall rule on your local machine that blocks you OR if you are connecting from a corporate network their firewall can also block you.

Comment: The firewall on my MacBook Air is turned off. but still nothing, unable to connect. Which never happened to me

Comment: What is your public IP for your EC2?

Comment: Is a IPv4. When I head to the ec2 and open that ip in the browser, it keeps loading until when it fails saying that is not responding. If my security group and my ACL allow all the traffic, what could it be stopping my connection?

Comment: @NaydenVan - Maybe check these and see if it helps. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html#TroubleshootingInstancesConnectionTimeout

Comment: Thank you so much. The solution was in the link you provided. Was a problem with the internet gateway not attached to the vpc and there was no association with the subnet. I put in place those those configurations and I was able to SSH inside.